# why is TypeScript converting string literal union type to string when assigning in object literal?

Tags: typescript, union-types

I love string literal union types in TypeScript.
I came across a simple case where I was expecting the union type to be retained.

Here is a simple version:

```js
let foo = false;
const bar = foo ? 'foo' : 'bar';

const foobar = {
    bar
}
```

`bar` is correctly typed as `'foo' | 'bar'`:

[image]

But `foobar.bar` gets typed as `string`:

[image]

Just curious why.

## Update

So @jcalz and @ggradnig do make good points. But then I realized my use case had an extra twist:

```js
type Status = 'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz';
let foo = false;
const bar: Status = foo ? 'foo' : 'bar';

const foobar = {
    bar
}
```

Interestingly, `bar` does have a type of `Status`. However `foobar.bar` has a type of `'foo' | 'bar'` still.

It seems that the only way to make it behave how I was expecting is to cast `'foo'` to `Status` like:

```js
const bar = foo ? 'foo' as Status : 'bar';
```

In that case, the typing does work properly. I am OK with that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The compiler uses some heuristics to determine [when to widen literals](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676).  One of them is the following:

> - The type inferred for a property in an object literal is the widened literal type of the expression unless the property has a contextual type that includes literal types.

So by default, that `"foo" | "bar"` gets widened to `string` inside the object literal you've assigned to `foobar`.

---

#### UPDATE FOR TS 3.4

You can now use [`const` assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to ask for narrower types:

```
const foobar = {
    bar
} as const;
/* const foobar: {
    readonly bar: "foo" | "bar";
} */
```

The `literally()` function in the rest of this answer may still be of some use, but I'd suggest using `as const` where possible.

---

Note the part of the heuristic that says "unless the property has a contextual type that includes literal types."  One of the ways to hint to the compiler that a type like `"foo" | "bar"` should stay narrowed is to have it match a type [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `string` (or a union containing it).

The following is a helper function I sometimes use to do this:

```
type Narrowable = string | number | boolean | symbol | object |
  null | undefined | void | ((...args: any[]) => any) | {};

const literally = <
  T extends V | Array<V | T> | { [k: string]: V | T },
  V extends Narrowable
>(t: T) => t;
```

The `literally()` function just returns its argument, but the type tends to be narrower. Yes, it's ugly... I keep it in a utils library out of sight.

Now you can do:

```
const foobar = literally({
  bar
});
```

and the type is inferred as `{ bar: "foo" | "bar" }` as you expected.

Whether or not you use something like `literally()`, I hope this helps you; good luck!

Answer (score 3):

That's because `let` and `const` are handled differently by TypeScript. Constants are always treated with the "narrower" type - in this case the literals. Variables (and non-readonly object properties) are treated with the "widened" type - `string`. This is a rule that comes along with literal types.

Now, while your second assignment may be a constant, the property of that constant is in fact mutable - it's a non-readonly property. If you don't provide a "contextual type", the narrow inference gets lost and you get the wider `string` type.

[Here you can read more about literal types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676). I may quote:

> The type inferred for a const variable or readonly property without a type annotation is the type of the initializer as-is.
>
> The type inferred for a `let` variable, `var` variable, `parameter`, or **`non-readonly property`** with an initializer and no type annotation is the widened literal type of the initializer.

And even more clearly:

> The type inferred for a property in an object literal is the widened literal type of the expression unless the property has a contextual type that includes literal types.

By the way, if you provide the contextual type for the constant, the type will be passed on to the variable:

```
const bar = foo ? 'foo' : 'bar';
let xyz = bar // xyz will be string

const bar: 'foo' | 'bar' = foo ? 'foo' : 'bar';
let xyz = bar // xyz will be 'foo' | 'bar'
```

Answer (score 3):

To answer the updated question with three-value literal union type:

```
type Status = 'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz';
let foo = false;
const bar: Status = foo ? 'foo' : 'bar';
```

Declared type of `bar` is Status, but it's inferred type is still narrowed by control flow analysis to only two possible values out of three, `'foo' | 'bar'`.

If you declare another variable without a type, TypeScript will use inferred type for `bar`, not the declared type:

```
const zoo = bar; // const zoo: "foo" | "bar"
```

Without resorting to type assertion `as Status`, there's no way to turn off type inference based on control flow analysis other than explicitly declaring the type at the place where you need it:

```
const foobar: {bar: Status} = {
    bar // has Status type now
}
```