# How can I type this coalesce function?

Tags: typescript

I'm relatively new to TypeScripts or anything beyond standard types in other typed languages for that matter, and I'm trying to figure out a good way to type this function. I want to get rid of the any type for the parameters and the return type.

The function returns the first value that is not null, undefined or NaN.

```
/** returns the first not-null value excluding NaN */
const coalesce = (...args: any): any => {
  for (let i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    // args[i] === args[i] is to avoid NaN, because NaN !== NaN
    if (args[i] != null && args[i] === args[i]) {
      return args[i];
    }
  }
  return null;
};
```

This is how you would use it:

```
test('coalesce returns the first value that is not null, undefined, NaN', () => {
  expect(coalesce(null, undefined, NaN, 'maybe')).toBe('maybe');
}); // -> passes
```

Comment: `coalesce(null, undefined, NaN, 'maybe')` contains strings and numbers, what should the return type be ? `string| number | null | undefined` ? Or just `string`. We can model, `null` and `undefied` in the type system `NaN` can't be represented

Comment: Yeah, [`NaN` is tough](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15135)... presumably if an input is of type `number` then the output needs to be a union containing `number | null`.

Comment: @jcalz Yeah that could be an option, I just ignored `NaN` in my solution ..  Not sure if treating `NaN` as null is the best way to go though...

Comment: I have something like a solution that actually tries to return the first non-null type in the tuple but I'm still debugging it... maybe I'll post it later if it seems viable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest version is to capture the type of the parameters types we pass in an type the return as a union of all parameter types.

We can use tuples in [rest parameters](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897) to capture the type of all parameters as a tuple type and [type queries](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)  to get a union of all types in the tuple:

```
const coalesce = <T extends any[]>(...args: T): T[number] => {
    for (let i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        // args[i] === args[i] is to avoid NaN, because NaN !== NaN
        if (args[i] != null && args[i] === args[i]) {
            return args[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
};


// o is  string | number | null | undefined under strict null checks
// T is [null, undefined, number, string] so T[number] is string | number | null | undefined
let o = coalesce(null, undefined, NaN, 'maybe')
```

Now the whole point of this function is to remove nulls and undefines (also `NaN`s but those are not modeled in the type system so there is nothing to do about those). The current signature leaves the `null` and the `undefined` in the type. We can add some mapped types and conditional types to remove the `null` and `undefined` if any of the parameters can't be `null` or `undefined` (as if one parameter is not `null` or `undefined` it will be returned)

```
type ExcludeNullIfAnyNotNullHelper<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]-?: (null extends T[P] ? never : null) |
        (undefined extends T[P] ? never : undefined) 
}[keyof T]
type ExcludeNullIfAnyNotNull<T extends any[]> = Exclude<T[number], ExcludeNullIfAnyNotNullHelper<T>>

type t1 = ExcludeNullIfAnyNotNull<[null, undefined, number, string]> // number | string
type t2 = ExcludeNullIfAnyNotNull<[null | string, string]> // string
type t3 = ExcludeNullIfAnyNotNull<[null | undefined | string, string]> // string
type t4 = ExcludeNullIfAnyNotNull<[null | undefined | string, string | null]> // string | null
type t5 = ExcludeNullIfAnyNotNull<[null | undefined | string, string | undefined]> // string | undefined
type t6 = ExcludeNullIfAnyNotNull<[null| undefined | string, string | undefined, number]> // string | number

function coalesce<T extends any[]>(...args: T): ExcludeNullIfAnyNotNull<T>
function coalesce<T extends any[]>(...args: T): T[number] {
    for (let i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        // args[i] === args[i] is to avoid NaN, because NaN !== NaN
        if (args[i] != null && args[i] === args[i]) {
            return args[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
};


// o is  string | number 
let o = coalesce(null, undefined, NaN, 'maybe')
```

Comment: Thanks Titian, the added code in your second example is a bit intimidating (until I familiarize myself with all the syntax, at least) but I understand what is going on generally. I assume there is no way to type this with the `@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any` ESLint rule turned on? If so I can just disable the rule for this file.

Comment: @Veinq `T extends unknown[]` should work just as well.

Comment: That works and doesn't trigger `no-explicit-any`. Thanks Titian!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so this is actually a fairly complicated type function you're trying to describe.

---

First of all, `NaN` presents a problem.  TypeScript has no representation for [`NaN` as a literal type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15135).  The value `NaN` is of type `number`.  So when you see a value of type `number`, it *might* be `NaN` and there's nothing the compiler can do to prevent that.  So when I see a `number` argument I will have to treat it as something like `number | null` for the purposes of `coalesce()`.  So this:

```
function hmm(n: number) { return coalesce(n, "oops"); }
```

should return a value of type `number | "oops"`, and not just `number`.  I can improve it a little bit, by explicitly recognizing that a numeric literal *cannot* be `NaN`, so that the following

```
coalesce(123, "oops");
```

should evaluate to `123` and not `123 | "oops"`, because `123` is a known non-`NaN` number.

---

So if you treat the arguments to `coalesce()` [as a tuple](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#generic-rest-parameters) then what you want is to walk through the tuple from left to right, building up a union of the types in the tuple, stripping off any possible `null` or `undefined` types.  If you come to a type which is definitely not `null`, `undefined`, or `number`, you can stop.  Otherwise you run off the end, add `null` to your union, and stop.

This type is naturally recursive in a way that is [not currently supported](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26980) by TypeScript.  There are a bunch of ways around this, but the only one that I'm sure behaves in a tractable way is to unroll the recursive type to some fixed depth and then bail out.

Let's start writing the types:

```
// Head<L>: return the first element of a tuple L
// Head<[string, number, boolean]> ~ string
type Head<L extends any[]> = ((...l: L) => void) extends
  ((h: infer H, ...t: infer T) => void) ? H : never;

// Tail<L>: return the tuple L with the first element removed
// Tail<[string, number, boolean]> ~ [number, boolean]
type Tail<L extends any[]> = ((...l: L) => void) extends
  ((h: infer H, ...t: infer T) => void) ? T : never;

// MightSkip<T>: return unknown if coalesce() might possibly skip a value 
//  of this type; return never if coalesce() will definitely stop at a value
//  of this type.  
// MightSkip<string | null> ~ unknown (might be null)
// MightSkip<string> ~ never
// MightSkip<number> ~ unknown (it might skip because NaN)
// MightSkip<123> ~ never (it knows 123 is not NaN)
type MightSkip<T> =
  null extends T ? unknown :
  undefined extends T ? unknown :
  [T] extends [number] ? (number extends T ? unknown : never) :
  number extends T ? unknown :
  never;
```

The recursive type function I want is this:

```
/* error, can't do this
type FirstNonNull<T extends any[]> = T['length'] extends 0 ? null :
  unknown extends MightSkip<Head<T>> ? NonNullable<Head<T>> | FirstNonNull<Tail<T>> : Head<T>;
*/
```

but it doesn't work because `FirstNonNull` is circular.  If you could write it, it would behave like this: if the argument tuple `T` is empty, it returns `null` (which happens if `coalesce()` gets to the end of its argument list).  Otherwise, if the first argument `Head<T>` might be skipped by `coalesce()`, you collect `NonNullable<Head<T>>` (removing `null` or `undefined`) into a union and keep going by calling `FirstNonNull` on `Tail<T>`.  Otherwise, you collect just `Head<T>` and stop.

We can't do circular types, so let's unroll that type like this:

```
type FirstNonNull<T extends any[]> = T['length'] extends 0 ? null :
  unknown extends MightSkip<Head<T>> ? NonNullable<Head<T>> | FirstNonNull0<Tail<T>> : Head<T>;
type FirstNonNull0<T extends any[]> = T['length'] extends 0 ? null :
  unknown extends MightSkip<Head<T>> ? NonNullable<Head<T>> | FirstNonNull1<Tail<T>> : Head<T>;
type FirstNonNull1<T extends any[]> = T['length'] extends 0 ? null :
  unknown extends MightSkip<Head<T>> ? NonNullable<Head<T>> | FirstNonNull2<Tail<T>> : Head<T>;
type FirstNonNull2<T extends any[]> = T['length'] extends 0 ? null :
  unknown extends MightSkip<Head<T>> ? NonNullable<Head<T>> | FirstNonNull3<Tail<T>> : Head<T>;
type FirstNonNull3<T extends any[]> = T['length'] extends 0 ? null :
  unknown extends MightSkip<Head<T>> ? NonNullable<Head<T>> | FirstNonNull4<Tail<T>> : Head<T>;
type FirstNonNull4<T extends any[]> = T['length'] extends 0 ? null :
  unknown extends MightSkip<Head<T>> ? NonNullable<Head<T>> | FirstNonNull5<Tail<T>> : Head<T>;
type FirstNonNull5<T extends any[]> = T['length'] extends 0 ? null :
  unknown extends MightSkip<Head<T>> ? NonNullable<Head<T>> | FirstNonNull6<Tail<T>> : Head<T>;
// as many as you need, and then bail out here:
type FirstNonNull6<T extends any[]> = NonNullable<T[number]> | null;
```

Notice how each `FirstNonNull1`, `FirstNonNull2`, etc type refers only to the next one, so that it isn't circular anymore.  The above should work for any tuple up to length 7 or so, before bailing out on longer argument lists with just the union of the remaining types.  If you expect longer argument lists you can extend the above scheme pretty easily.

---

Almost there: in order to capture arguments of literal type like `123` without having them automatically widened to non-literal types like `number`, we need to [give the compiler a hint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54334199/2887218), using a type like `Narrowable`.

```
type Narrowable = string | number | boolean | symbol | object |
  null | undefined | void | ((...args: any[]) => any) | {};
```

Finally, let's type `coalesce()` and see what the compiler tells us:

```
/** returns the first not-null value excluding NaN */
const coalesce = <T extends Narrowable[]>(...args: T): FirstNonNull<T> => {
  for (let i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    // args[i] === args[i] is to avoid NaN, because NaN !== NaN
    if (args[i] != null && args[i] === args[i]) {
      return args[i] as any; // assert
    }
  }
  return null as any; // assert
};
```

Yeah, the implementation of `coalesce()` needs an assertion on return values because it's hard for the compiler to verify that any value is of type `FirstNonNull<T>`.  It can be done with [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) instead of assertions; that's up to you.  And note how the elements of `T` are constrained to `Narrowable`, so that literals get inferred.  Here goes nothing:

```
const v0 = coalesce(null, undefined, "hey", "you"); 
// const v0: "hey"

// TypeScript doesn't have a NaN literal, so NaN is treated as number
const v1 = coalesce(null, undefined, NaN, 'maybe'); 
// const v1: number | "maybe"

const coinFlip = () => Math.random() < 0.5
const v2 = coalesce(coinFlip() ? "hey" : null, coinFlip() ? "you" : undefined, 123);
// const v2: "hey" | "you" | 123

const v3 = coalesce(undefined, undefined)
// const v3: null;
```

That looks about as good as I can imagine.  `v0` is just `"hey"`, not `"hey" | "you"`, because `coalesce()` will definitely stop at `"hey"`.  `v1` is `number | "maybe"` because the compiler sees `NaN` as `number`, so there's nothing better there. `v2` is `"hey" | "you" | 123` because either of the first two arguments might be null, but `123` is definitely not, so it has to be one of those three.  and `v3` is `null` because it fell off the end of the argument list.

---

Well that was a lot.  As I said, what you're doing is rather complicated to describe in the type system.  Maybe the above will be of some use to you.  Okay, good luck!