# Type annotations and discriminated union's of string literals

Tags: typescript, string-literals, discriminated-union

I've been having this issue with creating objects that conform to a type annotation (`Cards` in the example below), with a property that is of the type of a discriminated union of string literals (`CardType` in the example below), these string literals are the exact same string literals as on the original type annotation.

```
// ------------ SETUP ------------
interface AboutCard {
  type: 'About'
}

interface SplashCard {
  type: 'Splash'
}

export type Cards = AboutCard | SplashCard
export type CardType = 'About' | 'Splash'

const type = 'About' as CardType
// ------------ SETUP END ------------

const example1: Cards = {
  type
}

// ^
// Type 'CardType' is not assignable to type '"Splash"'.
// Type '"About"' is not assignable to type '"Splash"'.ts(2322)

const example2 = {
  type
} as Cards

// ^ all good, no error.

const example3 = {
  type: 'NOT_REAL_CARD'
} as Cards

// ^
// Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
// Type '"NOT_REAL_CARD"' is not comparable to type '"Splash"'.ts(2352)
```

So basically I'm wondering why that first example:

```
const example1: Cards = {
  type
}
```

is failing, but the last two examples are doing what I would expect.

`example1` seems to conform to the type `Cards`, and if you try explicitly setting `type` to either the string literal `About` or `Splash` it works fine, it's just when it can be the discriminated union that it has issues.

Sorry I don't know how to ask this better!

I feel like maybe this: [why is TypeScript converting string literal union type to string when assigning in object literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54333982/why-is-typescript-converting-string-literal-union-type-to-string-when-assigning) offers some clues as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Except for trivial cases where there are no other properties, `{ type: 'About' | 'Splash' }` is not the same as `{ type: 'About' } | { type: 'Splash' }`. Since your variable `type` is of the union of all possible discriminants, you are trying to do exactly this, assign an object with key `type` that is of a union property to where a discriminated union is expected.

The reason the latter two examples work, is you can do pretty much anything with a type assertion. You are effectively telling the compiler to suppress the type error it thinks is there.

To understand why these types are not compatible consider this example:

```
interface AboutCard {
    type: 'About'
    aboutMessage: string
}

interface SplashCard {
    type: 'Splash'
    spashMessage: string
}

export type Cards = AboutCard | SplashCard
export type CardType = Cards['type'] // no need to repeat string liteal types

const type = 'About' as CardType

// What properties should be required for `example1` ? 
// since it is both types at the same time best case scenario would be to require all properties in teh union
const example1: Cards = {
    type,
    spashMessage: ""
}
```

Comment: How would it be possible to make the above example work? Basically I have a `type` variable that can be either 'About' or 'Splash' and I want to construct a new `Cards` type dynamically with that `CardType`.

Also any chance you can go into more detail about why `{ type: 'About' | 'Splash' }` isn't the same as `{ type: 'About' } | { type: 'Splash' }`? 

Thanks so much!

Comment: Oh in your comment are you pointing out that `example1` can only be one of the two types of Cards? because only one of them has a `spashMessage`? So typescript isn't smart enough to figure out that just the type property can be either `About` or `Splash`?

Comment: @Shervanator it's not that TS is not smart enough, it's that you don't know which member of the union `example1` will be. Will it be `Splash` or `About` ? since `type` can be either we just don't know. This means we will not know which union member to check against. (Technically ts could require ALL union keys basically an intersection of all members but this is of limited value). You can use an `if` to differentiate the two cases or you can use a type assertion.