# Why is a typed string literal seen as (pure) string in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types, string-literals

If I have this pretty straight forward TypeScript code:

```
type example = 'BOOLEAN' | 'MULITSELECT' | '';

interface IObjectExample {
    a: string,
    readonly b: example
}

const handleObj = (obj: IObjectExample) :void => {
    console.log('have obj', obj);
}

const actualExample = {
    a: 'hello',
    b: 'BOOLEAN'
};

handleObj(actualExample); // error pops up here
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Argument of type '{ a: string; b: string; }' is not assignable to parameter
of type 'IObjectExample'. Types of property 'b' are incompatible.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'example'.
```

See [in the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=2&module=5#code/C4TwDgpgBBAeCGBbMAbaBeKByAQgeTwBkBRAQQDksoAfbAWQFVCBJAFQGViSBhVq2rFgDcAKBEBLAHbAIAJwBm8AMbRmeAEYArCEuDEEyNFADeIqFHgAuKAGdgsqQHMANGaiyI8ACYB7SShAodWs4JFQIEQBfMSU-OygAC3hJLzQNTShMAAofLWs1LR09A3CASihLADcfcS9MgD4TN3NYyRsfNAA6FB9HLKwkyuhczSxnKBHS0WiRVvjlYABXeBR9MKNMU3MrbASIFB6xt2DsfCIySijRESSUtK0sheXVkrQpoA).

It seems to be a ['widened literal type of the expression'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54334158/2092322) (here: `'BOOLEAN'`), but I have no clue why this happens. Additionally I'm not using `let` here, but even a `readonly` property.

Even more important: what should I use for ensuring a certain string literal as a property of an object, an `Enum`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tell typescript the variable's type:

```
const actualExample: IObjectExample = {
  a: 'hello',
  b: 'BOOLEAN'
};
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=2&module=5#code/C4TwDgpgBBAeCGBbMAbaBeKByAQgeTwBkBRAQQDksoAfbAWQFVCBJAFQGViSBhVq2rFgDcAKBEBLAHbAIAJwBm8AMbRmeAEYArCEuDEEyNFADeIqFHgAuKAGdgsqQHMANGaiyI8ACYB7SShAodWs4JFQIEQBfMSU-OygAC3hJLzQNTShMAAofLWs1LR09A3CASihLADcfcS9MgD4TN3NYyRsfNAA6FB9HLKwkyuhczSxnKBHS0WiRVvjlYABXeBR9MLR89KK1wwwm8ytsBIgUHrG3YOx8IjJKKNERJJS0rSyF5dWStCmgA)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have `readonly b: example`.
You need to tell TS compiler that `actualExample.b` is also readonly.

```js
const actualExample = {
  a: 'hello',
  b: 'BOOLEAN' as 'BOOLEAN' // <-- small trick
};
```

Now, there is no error:

```js
type example = 'BOOLEAN' | 'MULITSELECT' | '';

interface IObjectExample {
  a: string,
  readonly b: example
}

const handleObj = (obj: IObjectExample) :void => {
    console.log('have obj', obj);
}

const actualExample = {
  a: 'hello',
  b: 'BOOLEAN' as 'BOOLEAN'
};

// You can also add `as const` to actualExample variable
const actualExample2 = {
  a: 'hello',
  b: 'BOOLEAN'
} as const; // <-- works as well

handleObj(actualExample);
```

**UPDATE**
To ensure that some string is a property of an object, just use `keyof` operator.
See next example:

```js
const obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
}

type Obj = typeof obj;

const ensureStringIsObjectProperty = (arg: keyof Obj) => arg
const result = ensureStringIsObjectProperty('a') // only 'a' or 'b' are valid arguments
```